# How To Call A Callback Function After For Await Loop Ends

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to call a callback function in the scan function after for await loop ends. How can i do that?

```
let personObj = {};
let personArray = [];

 async function scan() {
    for await (const person of mapper.scan({valueConstructor: Person})) {
        decrypt(person.name, function () {
            personArray.push(personObj);
        });            
    }
}
```

Forexample i would like to call `console.log(personArray)` after the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to [promisify the callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) to use it in an `async` function:

```
function decryptAsync(value) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        decrypt(value, resolve);
    });
}
async function scan() {
    let personArray = [];
    for await (const person of mapper.scan({valueConstructor: Person})) {
        let personObj = await decryptAsync(person.name);
        personArray.push(personObj);
    }
    console.log(personArray)
}
```